# Jmeter, Unable to developed script for below mentioned scenario

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing

I have a scenario where I need configure jmeter to achieve:

1. 10 o'clock I have to trigger a request with 100 user. ( need to complete within 60 seconds/ramp up 60 seconds)
2. 10.05 .I need to trigger another request with 200 user. ( need to complete within 60 seconds/ramp up 60 seconds)
3. 10.10 . I need to trigger another request with 300 user. (need to complete within 60 seconds/ramp up 60 seconds)

5 min interval I need to trigger request and everytime 100 more user compare  to previous trigger. This way i need to reach 8000 user may be it takes 6 hours time.

This way I have to reach 8000 user (rampup 60 seconds). ( approx 6 hours overall time).

Comment: Not quite sure about what you mean by `8000 users`?

Comment: 1st  time 100 user, 2nd  time 200 user... n time 8000 user

Comment: Are you trying to find out what's your **max load**? I would say a `range` would be more accurate to this since the performance is just a metric, you can say your system can take `1_000` or `10_000` and you will not say that it's precisely about `10_100` and I will not buy that stuff.

Comment: 100 user to 8000 user.  100user/min .Pause 4 min. 200 user/min. Pause 4 min. 300user/min. pause 4min. ........8000User/min. Need a load testing report

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is going for [Stepping Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SteppingThreadGroup/) configured like:

[image: JMeter Stepping Thread GRoup]

The above configuration should match your scenario, you can amend holding 8000 users load and ramp-down period as required. See [Advanced Load Testing Scenarios with JMeter Part 4 - Stepping Thread Group and Concurrency Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-4-stepping-thread-group-and-concurrency-thread) article for more details if required.

You can install Stepping and/or Concurrency Thread Group extensions using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

Comment: Thanks a lot Dmitri, Let me try it